# glfwSetScrollCallback() compile failed

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I want to set a mouse scroll callback for my application,but there is always a error.Here is a code snippet:

```
void RambleController::scrollCallback(GLFWwindow *window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    _owner->move(_owner->getForward() * (float)yoffset * _zoomSpeed);
}

RambleController::RambleController(float moveSpeed, float lookAroundSpeed, float zoomSpeed, float slideAroundSpeed)
    :_moveSpeed{ moveSpeed }, _lookAroundSpeed{ lookAroundSpeed },
    _zoomSpeed{ zoomSpeed }, _slideAroundSpeed{ slideAroundSpeed } {
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scrollCallback);//Error here
}
```

Error   C3867

```
'violet::RambleController::scrollCallback': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

After I add & to the argument,there is other error like:

```
glfwSetScrollCallback(window, &scrollCallback);//

Error C2276'&': illegal operation on bound member function expression
```

Anyone know how to fix this?Ths.

Answer (score 5):

`scrollCallback` is a member function, so you cannot do `&scrollCallback` and get a normal function pointer. (You can use `&RambleController::scrollCallback` to get a member function pointer, which is useless for `glfwSetScrollCallback`)

Make sure your `scrollCallback` function is either `static`, or outside the class entirely.